# c# accessing class instance made in second class from a third class

Tags: c#

I've been trying to access an instance **lykkesHest** of my class **horse** from a third class **game**. But it tells me that the instance does not exist in the current context which makes sence because when **lykkesHest** hest is made it is not made as a public class. But when i try and make **lykkesHest** a public class instead it gives me a lot of weird error. I apologize for the text outputted to the user as it is danish.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lykkes_Hest
{
    // The class with the main game hidden inside it!
    class game
    {
        public static int money;
        public static double fodder;
        public game()
        {
            money = 1000;
            fodder = 1;
        }
        public static void help()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("#######################");
            Console.WriteLine("###### - HJÆLP - ######");
            Console.WriteLine("#######################");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Kommandoer du kan bruge:");
            Console.WriteLine("Hjælp - viser dig denne skærm");
            Console.WriteLine("fodre hesten - giver din hest mad hvis du har noget");
        }
        public static void exitSafely()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Er du sikker på at du vil forlade spillet?");
            Console.WriteLine("(Ja eller nej)");
            if(Program.getBool())
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
        public void RegisterCommand()
        {
            string command = Console.ReadLine();
            switch(command)
            {
                case "exit":
                    exitSafely();
                    break;
                case "vent":
                    lykkesHest.PassDay();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Ikke genkendt kommando.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    // A class for making a horse
    class horse
    {
        public string name;
        public double age = 0;
        public string color;
        public double hunger = 50;
        public double boredom = 50;

        public horse()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hvad skal din hest hedde?");
            name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Hvor mange år er din hest?");
            while (age == 0) {
                try
                {
                    age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                } catch {
                    Console.WriteLine("Do skal skrive et tal.");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hvilken farve har din hest?");
            color = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Din hest heder {0} er {1} år gammel og har farven {2}", name, age, color);
        }
        public static void Die(string cause)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Din hest døde af {0}........", cause);
            Console.WriteLine("Du burde passe bedre på den en anden gang!");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Klik på en knap for at afslutte.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        public void PassDay()
        {
            hunger =+ 10;
            boredom =+ 10;
            if(hunger >= 100 || boredom >= 100)
            {
                horse.Die("sult");
            } else if(boredom >= 100)
            {
                horse.Die("Kedsomhed");
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static bool getBool()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string answer = Console.ReadLine();
                if (answer.ToLower() == "ja")
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (answer.ToLower() == "nej")
                {
                    return false;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Du må kun skrive ja eller nej");
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Get passowrd
            Console.WriteLine("HVAD ER KODEORDET FOR AT MÅ SPILLE DET HER AMAZING SPIL?");
            if (Console.ReadLine().ToLower() != "what is password?")
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            // Initialize the game
            game Spil = new game();

            Console.WriteLine("###############################");
            Console.WriteLine("######## -Lykkes Hest- ########");
            Console.WriteLine("###############################");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Velommen, du spiller version 001");
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Create a basic horse
            horse lykkesHest = new horse();
            lykkesHest.Print();
            Console.WriteLine("Er dette korrekt?");
            while(getBool() == false)
            {
                lykkesHest = new horse();
            }

            // Optional tutorial
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Vil du gerne lære de kommandoer du kan bruge?");
            Console.WriteLine("(Ja eller nej)");
            if (getBool())
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Lykkes hest er et interaktivt sandbox spil hvor du styrer EN FUCKING HEST!!");
                Console.WriteLine("Du bestemmer selv om du vil have din hest til at en flotter præmie hest eller en sy' hurtig ræcer!");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Du spiller ved at skrive nogle få kommandoer ind i kommando linjen (Den du læser fra lige nu).");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Hvis du nogensinde glemmer en kommando eller vil lære nogle nye kan du altid skrive 'Hjælp' for at få dem vist.");
                Console.WriteLine("Og hvis du nogensinde vil stoppe spillet kan du gøre det ved at skrive 'exit'");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Loop the rest of the game
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("#####################################################");
                Console.WriteLine("Penge: {0} - Foder: {1}", game.money, game.fodder);
                Console.WriteLine("Hestens sult: {0} - Hestens kedsomhed: {1}", lykkesHest.hunger, lykkesHest.boredom);
                Console.WriteLine("#####################################################");
                game.RegisterCommand();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you mark the line where you get an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the game is about managing a horse, then the game class (which you should be calling Game to follow usual naming conventions) should contain a field of type horse:

```
class Horse
{
    public int Age{ get; private set };
    public int Hunger { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; } 

    public Horse(string name)
    {  
        Name = name;
        Age = 0;
        Hunger = 0;
    }     

    public bool IsDead() 
    {
       return Hunger >= 100 || Age > 3650;
    }

    void PassDay()
    {
       Age = Age + 1;
       Hunger = Hunger + 1;
    }

    void Feed()
    {
       Hunger = 0;
    }

    // etc.

    public override string ToString() 
    {
      return string.Format("{0} Age {1}", Name, Age);
    }
}
```

Either the game can *create* it's own horse instance, or you have to *pass* the horse instance into the Game's constructor. 
If the game manages *one* horse, and the game always has exactly *one* horse, it's a good practice to assign it in the constructor so that you can't even have a game without a horse.

I translated (and changed) your game somewhat to make the example clearer.

```
class Game
{
     private readonly Horse horse;
     private int money;
     // more things

     public Game(Horse horse, int money)
     {             
        this.horse = horse;
        this.money = money;
     }

     public bool IsOver
     {
        get { return horse.IsDead(); }
     }

}
```

The main program class is very different. It's a static class and contains only static methods. The other classes (horse, game) are classes of which you create objects. You have *one* game, which has *one* horse and so on.

```
public static class Program
{
     private static Game game;

     public static void Main()
     {
         game = CreateNewGame();
         do
         {
            // get input
            // update game state
         } while (!game.IsOver);
     }

     private static Game CreateNewGame()
     {
        Horse horse;
        do
        {
           horse = CreateRandomHorse();
           Console.WriteLine("Is this ok? : " + horse); // Calls horse.ToString()
        } while (!GetBoolInput());

        // have a horse, can make a game
        return new Game(horse, 100);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was really usefull.

Comment: Having someone correct and give tips is the most helpfull thing when you are just starting out on coding.

Comment: You are declaring `horse` in the `do` block, it should not be available outside this block. I think this has been the original authors issue, too.

Comment: Thanks, horse moved. It still doesn't work of course, there are lots of things *missing* from the loop, such as displaying the horse, etc. but now at least the scopes should be ok, which was one of the original issues.

Comment: Added a ToString() and a display. This is evolving to a mini C# tutorial , there are likely better places for those :)